# How to add carriage return to bash when prompted for ssh password to localhost?

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash and was tasked with scripting a check for a compliance process.

From bash (or if python is better), I need to script an ssh connection from within the host running the script.

For example:
ssh -l testaccount localhost

But I need to run this 52 times so that it is trapped by an IPS.

When running this string I am prompted for a password and I have to hit enter in order to make the script complete.

Is there a way to include a password or carriage return to act as manual intervention so that I do not have to hit enter each time?

Here's a sample of what I was able to get working, but it only sequenced 30 attempts:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while [$i -lt 52]
do
echo | ssh -l testaccount localhost&
i=$[$i+1]
done
```

Comment: the easy way is the add the private key to the known_users generate ssh key for every account and add to the servers ssh this very fast and that the way to bypass typing or parsing password. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Client_Configuration_Files

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. However, the org wants to intentionally perform 52 failed logins with a bad password. That way the failed logins are trapped in messages, forwarded to a SIEM and used as evidence that logging is still working. It's a ridiculous requirement and I've argued with the business about this approach, but they insist on using this method.

Comment: easy install fail2ban and configure the failed login as 52 you have just install like this : sudo apt-get install fail2ban https://www.linode.com/docs/security/using-fail2ban-for-security

Comment: Read about [`sshpass`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sshpass.1.html)

Comment: Another restriction we have is the server (rhel based) is locked down tighter than a snare drum. No additional software can be installed on it. :/

Comment: Thanks, Glenn Jackman. However, as I mentioned to headmax, the org refuses to install additional software/tools on this host since it is bound to several federal government compliance standards. So scripting is the only method.

Comment: Sorry i didn't read about your restriction :(, yes the only way as you said old school coding gl, to be continue :).

Answer (score 0):

Fail2ban configuration and good practice :

```
//count how password as root failed
cat /var/log/secure.1 | grep "Failed password for root" --count

//check the list for analyst
cat /var/log/secure.1 | grep "Failed password for root"

//setting fail2ban copy for local configuration
cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
//open the configuration file and edit some secu
 sudo nano /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
 maxfailures = 5  //here you have to set to 56 as you said
 bantime = 600  //here time during second try login
 ignoreip = 192.168.0.0/16 //add the lan and ip online static
 [mail]
 enabled = false  //true if you want to alert you IP blacklisted banned ...
 //log traffic
 cat /var/log/fail2ban.log
 [ssh]
 //network protocole protection & supervision
 enabled = true
 port    = ssh,sftp
 filter  = sshd
 logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
 maxretry = 6

 //enable fail2ban
 systemctl enable fail2ban
//start fail2ban
 systemctl start fail2ban
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: While `expect` comes in its own package, `expect` was already in my SLES base installs ... don't know if this would be true for RHEL, too ... ?

Take a look at this [answer on how to automate SSH with a password](https://serverfault.com/a/241589).

I'm thinking you could probably re-use the `expect` script from that post to simulate a single failed login, eg:

- either set `pass` to a bogus value or don't set at all
- if you don't set `pass` then remove the `send -- "$pass\r"` clause
- if the remote system re-prompts X times for a password then provide multiple copies of the `expect/send` commands (a few extras will generate some `expect` related errors but still cause a failed ssh login)

---

For one of my remote hosts I'm prompted 3 times to enter a password before I'm returned to the command prompt.

I whipped up the following test:

```
$ cat sshtest
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set pass xyz
set server myremotehost
set name bob

spawn ssh $name@$server
match_max 100000
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "\r"
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "\r"
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "\r"
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "\r"
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "\r"
interact
```

And the results of running the script:

```
$ sshtest
spawn ssh bob@myremotehost
Password:
Password:
Password:
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
send: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"send -- "\r""
    (file "sshtest" line 16)
```

If you don't have enough `expect/send` pairs then you'll be left stranded with a `Password:` prompt, so I added a few extra `expect/send` pairs, which in turn generated those last 4 lines of the output. [I don't use `expect` so there may be a more graceful way to do this ... ymmv.]

Obviously your main script could call this script and place said call in the background, and do whatever you want with the output (`>/dev/null 2>&1` ??)

I also verified on the remote host that the failed logins were logged in `/var/log/warn` and `/var/log/messages`.